# SWIFT4 - Refreshing Data From Server

Tags: swift, xcode

I think I must be missing something. I have an app that loads table reservations on an iPad and in order to stay up to date, I refresh the main-page-ist every 15 seconds.

Instead I want to refresh the page only when there is a change. I want it to work like a push notification that tells my app that there has to be a change and that it needs to connect to the server and update, but some users are turning push notification off and i have no control over that. There must be a better solution I'm missing right here.

How are messaging apps doing this. How do viber, whatsApp facebook messengers know that there is a new message and show it immediately. I don't think they connect to the server every seconds... or do they?

Comment: You could use a technology like Pusher (https://pusher.com) to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is common but not advisable these days.  **You want to push, not pull.**  What do I mean?  How often someone reserves a new table is random, so it could be 5 seconds or every 5 hours.  In your case, if you refresh every 15 seconds it could be killing the battery and gobbling up data unnecessarily.

**The better way is for you to set up a push server that, when a table is booked, your push server sends a push notification to your app.**  This way, whether instead of asking all the time "hey, any reservations?"  your server tells you when a booking event happens.

Of course this requires more work on your part, but you will run into the same issue over and over again, so it's worth looking into how to do this.

If you're at a larger company, and only doing front end, you need to have the backend engineers build a push server for you.

This is how What's app and other apps notify you when you have a message.

Answer (score 1):

I think, `Silent Push Notification` is the best solution for your case.

You can still catch the information in the background even user does not permit push notifications.